Playbook only writes one server per run, but will write the other server the next time
My playbook is very simple, but it only puts one line in the file everytime I run it. Its correct for the entry it does, but why doesn't it do all the servers in the play?
tasks:
  - name: get the hostname for the play
    setup:
      filter: "ansible_hostname"

  - name: Get lines without '#' in front
    shell: grep -v '^\s*#' /etc/sudoers  
    register: sudofile

  - name: check sudo files for recent changes
    lineinfile:
      path: "/scratch/ansible/out/sudo.csv"
      line: "{{  ansible_hostname  }}  {{  sudofile.stdout_lines  }}"
      create: yes
    delegate_to: localhost

I expected it to run through every host and to print a line for each host. I looked at a debug when I run it on two hosts and it gathers all the correct data, it only writes the last servers info unless I run it twice.

See the duplicate. tl;dr: add throttle: 1 as a task (not module) option.
